# samsung Galaxy s firmware

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I had a message about running out of space on my GT-i9000 so like a fool I started deleting things...turns out I deleted most of my operating system is there somewhere I can download the os rather than sending back to the manufacturer (and is this the firmwear)

Comment: You rooted your device?

Answer (score 2):

[Samfirmware.com](http://samfirmware.com) or [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=656) are your best bets.  If you need instructions for flashing with Odin or recovery, we have lots of questions on that so just do a search :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a recovery of firmware using Samsung Kies software.